# Server Side Ajax JQuery CRUD DataTable - PHP PDO, MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to fetch data from child table using Id stored in the child table to populate DataTable and display records related to Parent table and child table. Below is the code:

Problem is when I add WHERE statement to fetch records based on HolderID shows number of entries returned but not displayed. And filtered also shows 0
Code:

```
function get_beneficaries_records($rowId)
{
    include('db.php');
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM beneficiaries WHERE HolderID = $rowId");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

Fetching records on fectchrecords.php.

$query .= "SELECT * FROM pro_beneficiaries";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
    $query .= ' WHERE BeneficiaryIDNo LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';

    $query .= 'OR LastName LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';

    $query .= 'OR Initials LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
    $query .= 'OR BeneficiaryIDNo LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE FK_HolderID = $rowIds';
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
} 
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY BID DESC ';
}
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
    $query .= ' WHERE BeneficiaryID LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}

$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();


foreach($result as $row)
{

    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row["Initials"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["LastName"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["BeneficiaryIDNo"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["Relationship"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["MemberType"];
    
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["BID"].'" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-xs updatebeneficiary"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["BID"].'" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs deletebeneficiary"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_beneficaries_records($rowId),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: It seems like this is more a question about the sql query than ajax.

Comment: Concour @RayB And for a question would you be able to remove as much as possible and still be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: @RayB and Anton Krug ,The issue still persists all I need is to fetch and populate data into datatable  WHERE HolderID = $rowId but doesn't seem to work

Comment: you're already using prepared statements, why are you still injecting the values directly in your query. use placeholders and use your variables as payload in  the execute function

Comment: @Kevin do you perhaps have an example on how I could implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I would print raw content of the query result, I would print the query itself so I see what the code produced, then I could run it in a separate client (I love HeidiSQL for this).

And I think there might a condition where it will put duplicate WHERE

```
if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
    $query .= 'WHERE FK_HolderID = $rowIds';
} 

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
    $query .= ' WHERE BeneficiaryID LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}
```

I would form it into one WHERE and use boolean AND OR to form the conditions I want

Comment: Anton Krug, Kindly advise how I would implement this solution